# SQLInForm.com like plug-in for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, formatting

Is there a plug-in like the java applet @ SQLinForm.com for MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

I tried SSMS tools based on someone's answer to my previous question but I don't find any functionality to format (beautify/tabify) SQL.

If somebody could please point out that in SSMS tools or suggest some other tool (preferably free)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found something online which is free:

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm